# Why does "i, j = 1" result in "int .. is not iterable"?

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a partition function for quicksort in Python.

```
def partition(ls):
  if len(ls) == 0:
    return
  pivot = ls[0]
  i, j = 1
  while j < len(ls):
    if ls[j] <= pivot:
      i += 1
      temp = ls[i]
      ls[i] = ls[j]
      ls[j] = temp
    j += 1
  ls[0] = ls[i]
  ls[i] = pivot
```

However, Python issues this error when I call `quicksort.partition([1,2,3])`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "quicksort.py", line 5, in partition
    i, j = 1
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What is this error saying? Of course, int objects are not iterable, but when did I ever iterate over an int object?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you think `i,j = 1` was going to assign 1 to both variables?

Comment: You kinda got the error in the error message: `i, j = 1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you list multiple targets separated by commas on the left of an assignment, it tries to iterate over the right hand side and assign pieces to the pieces on the left.  So if you do `x, y = (1, 2)` then x will be 1 and y will be 2.

If you want to make i and j both be 1, do `i = j = 1`.

(Note that this binds both variables to the same object.  It's fine for this case, but if you are assigning a mutable object (like `x = y = []`) you should remember that both x and y will be pointing to the same list, so mutations will affect both `x` and `y`.)

Answer (score 3):

```
i, j = 1
```

This piece of code is (functionally) equivalent to:

```
i = None
for a in 1:
    if i != None and j != None:
        break
    if i == None:
        i = a
    else
        j = a
```

Which is, of course, illegal, as `1` is not iterable, and that's what the interpreter is telling you.

What you want is:

```
i = j = 1
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Why is it testing `if i == 0`?

Comment: I don't think this is a helpful way of looking at it.

Comment: @RussellBorogove, it explains where **exactly** does the `iterable` part comes from.

Comment: But it does nothing in the way of explaining the general tuple assignment construct.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> i,j=1,2
>>> i,j=[1,2]
>>> i,j=(1,2)
>>> i,j='12'
>>> i,j={1,2}
>>> i,j={'x':1,'y':1}
```

works fine for all of these

so `i,j` type of assignment works only if on the Right side of `=` you either provide two comma separated values or an `iterable` with two values.